# How to fetch csv data using SplFileObject in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error

I have a CSV file named `beatles.csv` that has the following contents on each cell:

```
John,Paul,George,Ringo
```

In vanilla PHP, this code works without issue (CSV file is in the same location as the script):

```
$data = 'beatles.csv';
$file = new SplFileObject($data);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    echo $row[0].'<br>'; // outputs John
}
```

In Laravel 5.4, I created a folder named `MyDomainName` under the `app` folder and I put the CSV file there so its namespaced as follows:

```
use App\MyDomainName;
```

And the content of my method on the controller which should fetch the CSV data is as follow:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\MyDomainName;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function fetchCSV()
    {
        $file = new SplFileObject('beatles.csv');
        $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
        foreach ($file as $row){
            dd($row[0]);
        }         
    }
}
```

And I get this issue:

> **FatalThrowableError in PageController.php line 67**:
>       Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SplFileObject' not found

I thought that by using `use App\MyDomainName;` it will solve the issue but still it didn't solve it.

I have also explicitly use the full path but still it didn't work.

```
$file = new \App\MyDomainName\SplFileObject('App\MyDomainName\beatles.csv');
```

and I still get the same error:

```
FatalThrowableError in PageController.php line 67:
Class 'App\MyDomainName\SplFileObject' not found
```

What could be the issue why is it that the `SplFileObject` class cannot be found?

Comment: Namespacing! Namespacing! Namespacing! `SplFileObject` is in the __global__ namespace; so `$file = new \SplFileObject('beatles.csv');` and `$file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);`

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at http://csv.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score 2):

In your `fetchCSV` method replace this code

```
$file = new \SplFileObject('beatles.csv');
```

I've faced the same use. You just need to add the forward-slash before `SplFileObject()`

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Mark Baker, the issue is now solved:

```
public function fetchCSV()
    {
        $file = new \SplFileObject('../App/MyDomainName/beatles.csv');
        $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
        foreach ($file as $row){
            dd($row[0]); // outputs "John"
        }         
    }
```